# What widgets to use to display realtime data from firestore to text edit and any changes be updated

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of meals, I want to pull the meals from firestore and display in textformfield and make it editable, where then the update be applied to firestore.

Whenever I supply the string to initial value along with textedit controller, I get either that it can only be static or this error

> Failed assertion: line 72 pos 15: 'initialValue
>   I/flutter (23302): == null || controller == null': is not true.
>   from issue:
>   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18044

any input on what i should use to pull some data in realtime and display it to be able make it editable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot supply a `TextEditingController` and an `initialValue` (at the same time).

It sounds like you want to leverage a textEditingController to pull the data from the input (on a submit event of sorts). This is reasonable, but I will also note `onSubmitted` and `onChanged` callbacks available on the TextField widget - but you can certainly achieve your goals with the TextFormField.

To do this, you need to initialize the TextEditingController with the initial value via its [constructor](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/TextEditingController.html) (perhaps in `initState()`)

```
  TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = TextEditingController(text: "Some String");
  }
```

Comment: that worked, why did we need to make a call to super.init ?

Comment: @Tegster007, the containing widget extends StatefulWidget. StatefulWidget defines the initState() method that we are overriding with `@override`. If we don't call `super.initState` we will affect the lifesycle of the StatefuleWidget. You will also probably see a warning as it is marked with `@mustCallSuper`